# Turn The Whole Group of Inputs Off?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a sessions script and I am currently able to turn the sessions off 1 by 1 (London Session, New York Session, Tokyo Session, Sydney Session) but I would like to be able to turn them all off with 1 checkbox.

Also, I know I can jsut click the eyeball to hide the indicator in the upper left, but I want to do this within the settings if possible.

The pinescript:

```
//@version=5


indicator('Sessions', overlay=true)

bgColor = input(title='Activate High/Low View', defval=false)

LondonColor = color.green
NYColor = color.red
AsiaColor = color.yellow
SydneyColor = color.navy

///Session Times
res = input.timeframe(title='Resolution', defval='D', options=['D', 'W', 'M'])
london = input.session(title='London Session', defval='0300-1200:1234567')
ny = input.session(title='New York Session', defval='0800-1700:1234567')
tokyo = input.session(title='Tokyo Session', defval='2000-0400:1234567')
sydney = input.session(title='Sydney Session', defval='1700-0200:1234567')

//Bars
is_newbar(sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

is_session(sess) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sess))

//London
London = input(title='London Session', defval=true, group='one checkbox')
londonSession = is_session(london)
bgcolor(londonSession and London and not bgColor ? LondonColor : na, transp=90)

//New York
NY = input(title='New York Session', defval=true, group='one checkbox')
nyNewbar = is_newbar(ny)
nySession = is_session(ny)
bgcolor(nySession and NY and not bgColor ? NYColor : na, transp=90)

//Tokyo
Tokyo = input(title='Tokyo Session', defval=true, group='one checkbox')
tokyoSession = is_session(tokyo)
bgcolor(tokyoSession and Tokyo and not bgColor ? AsiaColor : na, transp=90)

//Sydney
Sydney = input(title='Sydney Session', defval=false, group='one checkbox')
sydneySession = is_session(sydney)
bgcolor(sydneySession and Sydney and not bgColor ? SydneyColor : na, transp=90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another input.bool() and combine it with your existing conditions used in bgcolor()

```
showSessions = input.bool(true, title = "Display Sessions?")
...
...
londonSession = showSessions and is_session(london)
...
...
nySession = showSessions and is_session(ny)
...
etc
```